# Не работает алгоритм сортировки первых элементов строк методом выбора

Tags: c++

```
int b,i,j,k,min;
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++){
min=i;
for (k=0; k<n-1; k++){
if (a[min][0]>a[min+1][0]){
    min=k;
    for (j=0; j<m; j++){
    b=a[min][j];
    a[min][j]=a[min+1][j];
    a[min+1][j]=b;
        }
    }
    }
}
Это код для сортировки строк методом простого выбора двумерного массива по первому элементу каждой строки. Он работает и переставляет строки, но не сортирует по первому столбцу матрицы. Я не знаю почему он не работает, провёл множество манипуляций с кодом, но не помогло.
```

Comment: Подтверждаю

Comment: @vadim777, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.